# Display boolean as true/false instead of 1/0 in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstableview

In the implementation of the`NSTableViewDataSource` method

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!
```

, the returned result for a column is a native Swift `Bool`-typed value. I expected it being displayed as `true` or `false` in the table view. However, it is actually displayed as `1` or `0`. I guess it might have been casted to `AnyObject` and became an Obj-C object. What's an easy way to make them displayed as `true` or `false` in the table view?

Comment: Implement custom formatter (NSFormatter) and set it to table column's textFieldCell. You may also use NSButtonCell to show check boxes instead of true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C `Bool` type is actually an `signed char` under the covers.

```
objc.h:typedef signed char BOOL; 
objc.h:#define YES             ((BOOL)1)
objc.h:#define NO              ((BOOL)0)
```

So when you return this as an object, you're actually returning something that gets cast to an NSInteger, which is why it's showing a `0` or `1`.

To solve this, modify your object method to return

```
return theBoolValue ? @"true" : @"false"
```

Comment: But how do I know if it is a real bool value? I don't want to display "true" for other column with integer type value 1.

Comment: The data source should return values as-is when possible. It's formatter's and/or value transformer's job to format/transform values in/from cells

Comment: Silly approach - in the Cocoa universe that's a job for `NSValueTransformer`